# Loading HTML Data into various views

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode5, html-parsing

I'm attempting to create a native app for the website [3v3live.com](http://www.3v3live.com), but I've been unable to load data from the website (no errors or warnings; I'm using [Hpple](https://github.com/topfunky/hpple)). For example, in my first view ("Home") I wanted to load all the text from the home page of 3v3live.com into a dynamic table view via container view. So I created a subclass of UITableViewController ("homeTVClass"), and created an IBOutlet in the .h file for the Table View in my Home view.

My .h file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface homeTVClass : UITableViewController

@property (weak,nonatomic) NSArray * homeArrayTVC;
- (id) fromURL: (NSString*) urlS ParseDataWithPath: (NSString*) path WithType: (NSString*) typeOfDataToReturn;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *homeText;

@end
```

My .m file:

```
#import "homeTVClass.h"
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "TFHpple.h"
#import "TFHppleElement.h"

@interface homeTVClass ()
- (id) fromURL: (NSString*) urlS ParseDataWithPath: (NSString*) path WithType: (NSString*) typeOfDataToReturn;
@end

@implementation homeTVClass

@synthesize homeArrayTVC;
@synthesize homeText;



- (id) fromURL: (NSString*) urlS ParseDataWithPath: (NSString*) path WithType: (NSString*) typeOfDataToReturn
{
    // Set up request
    NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlS];
    NSData * gatheredData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

    // set up parser
    TFHpple * Parser = [TFHpple hppleWithHTMLData: gatheredData];

    // parse data
    NSArray * Nodes = [Parser searchWithXPathQuery:path];

    // Set up array to be returned
    NSMutableArray * array = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:0];

    // Insert parsed data into "array"
    for (TFHppleElement * element in Nodes)
    {
        // tell returned data it's class
        id dataType = NSClassFromString(typeOfDataToReturn);
        id returnedData = [[dataType alloc] init];
        // set returnedData's value and insert it into "array"
        returnedData= [[element firstChild] content];
        [array addObject:returnedData];
    }
    return array;
    [self.tableView reloadData];// added for TV
}

- (void) getData
{
    // load data from website into an array that entire file can access
    [homeArrayTVC arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:
     [self fromURL:@"http://www.3v3live.com" ParseDataWithPath: @"//div[@class = 'description']/h3" WithType:@"NSString"]]; // home
}



- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self getData];

    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations.
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 0;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return [homeArrayTVC count];
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell * cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"myCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Configure the cell...
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"myCell"];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [homeArrayTVC objectAtIndex: indexPath.row]; // use data from homeArrayTVC to create cells
    return cell;
}



// Override to support conditional editing of the table view.
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Return NO if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
    return NO;
}
@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have quite a few problems in your code.  First of all, you cannot call any methods after the return in a method.  So the following lines need to be reversed:

```
    return array;
    [self.tableView reloadData];// added for TV
}
```

But, as this is one of the other problems , for now simly remove the `reloadTable:` call (you'll be moving it to the `getData` call later):

```
    // [self.tableView reloadData];// added for TV
    return array;
}
```

Next, your method should just return an NSArray instead of id.  Not specifying the return type is not something you should be doing unless you have a valid reason, and you do not in the case:

```
- (NSArray*) fromURL: (NSString*) urlS ParseDataWithPath: (NSString*) path WithType: (NSString*) typeOfDataToReturn
```

Now that the method has the correct return type in the definition, change the method to return an NSArray instead of the NSMutableArray by changing this in your `fromURL` method:

```
return [array copy]; // this returns an immutable copy of the NSMutableArray
```

Next, you never initialize `homeArrayTVC`.  Basically it will be nil, and it will never be anything other than nil. That's fine as long as you realize that it is a non-mutable array, meaning you can't alter the contents (add or remove things from the array). Given the next error and the fix I'm providing, that's probably OK.

Finally, you need to read up on how NSArrays work.  The following method is not doing anything with the results from the `fromURL:` call:

```
- (void) getData
{
    // load data from website into an array that entire file can access
    [homeArrayTVC arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:
     [self fromURL:@"http://www.3v3live.com" ParseDataWithPath: @"//div[@class = 'description']/h3" WithType:@"NSString"]]; // home
}
```

Basically, when you call `[arrayObj arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:otherArray];`, it returns a new array with the contents of both arrays.  For some reason you are trying to append the results from the web call to a nil array, which returns nil.  And then you don't do anything with the results of the `arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:` call.  So the fact that it is nil doesn't really matter.  All that said, I think all you really want to do is save the results from the `fromURL:` call.  To do that, try this (I would also move the incorrect reloadTable call to here, since you don't want to do that until you have assigned the results to the homeArrayTVC attribute:

```
- (void) getData
{
    // load data from website into an array that entire file can access
    homeArrayTVC =
     [self fromURL:@"http://www.3v3live.com" ParseDataWithPath: @"//div[@class = 'description']/h3" WithType:@"NSString"]; // home
    [self.tableView reloadData];// added for TV
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks for fixing all those issues (I'm still incredibly new to this), but after I implemented your solution nothing changed. Is there anything wrong in the part where I create the Table Cell?

Comment: I would set a breakpoint in the `numberOfRowsInSection` method.  If it doesn't get hit, you likely haven't set up your tableview delegate properly.  You can do it in code by making this call in your viewDidLoad: `self.tableView.delegate = self;`